# Convert byte array to escaped string

Tags: java, ascii

I need some help converting a java byte array to a 7-Bit ASCII string. However I am getting 8-bit sequences and need to escape any unreadable character to it's escaped sequence. Is there a simple solution for this or do I need to build my own?

Seeing that the range of readable characters in 7-bit ASCII is continuous right now I am thinking of the following:

```
for( int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++ ) {
   int codePoint = ( (int) buffer[ i ] ) & 255;
   if( 0x20 <= codePoint && codePoint <= 0x7e ) {
      res = res + String( (char) codePoint );
   } else {
     String c = Integer.toHexString( codePoint );
     if( c.length() < 2 ) {
       c = "0" + c;
     }
     res = res + "\\0x" + c;
   }
}
```

However this seems like an awful lot of work for such a simple conversion. Is there a better way?

Also I might need to do the same to data that has been converted from the byte array to strings. Is there a simpler solution in this case?

Comment: That's exactly what base64 was designed for. For strings, use the `getBytes(Charset)` method (You must decide which character set encoding you want the output to be in).

Comment: `0x20 >= codePoint && codePoint >= 0x7e` is always false.  I think you meant `<=`.

Comment: @Jim: Yes, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: No, Base64 is not what I need here. I don't need any kind of encoding of the full 8Bits, but a human readable one. The reason being, that I want to log strings, which might also contain some additional header in the front, which I want to print as simple as possible. It might actually be simpler just to decode the header and print this as well in a decoded manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public static String escape(byte[] data) {
    StringBuilder cbuf = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : data) {
      if (b >= 0x20 && b <= 0x7e) {
        cbuf.append((char) b);
      } else {
        cbuf.append(String.format("\\0x%02x", b & 0xFF));
      }
    }
    return cbuf.toString();
  }
```

You can use the [format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method to pare back the verbiage.

*Note that this method is only safe because the ASCII range matches the lower range of the UTF-16 encoding used by Java Strings.*

Comment: A bit more clean than the way I did it, but still seems like a lot of work for such a simple task. Accepted because I solved the problem in a completely unrelated way that makes the whole program much cleaner.

Answer (score -2):

If it doesn't fit base64 so second standard is `java.net.URLEncoder`.